# How to append a div via PHP and AJAX Post

Tags: php, html, ajax

Good day. I'm trying to make an online quiz application using php. The idea is that the form will add a text field for the question and four other text fields below it for the answers each with a radio button to determine which one is correct. Then below the form is an add a new question button which would call an ajax post function. The problem is instead of appending to the target div, the php code replaces the contents of the div itself. Is there a way for php to append to the div instead of replace its contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is server-side, it can't do anything in the browser, only deliver content.

To add a div, you use Javascript in the page, e.g.

```
var el = document.getElementById('idoftarget');
el.innerHTML += '<div>new stuff</div>
```

... I think. I always use jQuery:

```
$('#idoftarget').append('<div>new stuff</div>');
```

Comment: No, php is always server side, while client side script is Javascript. Often what you know how to do in PHP language/syntax/frameworks can be translated to Javascript.

Comment: Although it's typically considered bad practice, you CAN do the same thing via your PHP script. `echo "<script>$('#idoftarget').append('<div>new stuff</div>');</script>";` Just be careful when you use PHP like that, because you have to take into consideration that PHP runs BEFORE the other stuff, so you may not get the exact effect you're wanting (depends what you're doing). To answer your other question, you can have a separate PHP file and simply call it from the script, which is basically what you're asking and a better solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

how are you handling the ajax response? maybe instead (since you don't have code here it's a guess) of

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML=ajaxResponseText;
```

you want

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML+=ajaxResponseText;
```

(appending rather than overwriting)

Answer (score 2):

This is the right one:

```
document.getElementById('exampleDIV').innerHTML+=ajaxResponseText;
```