# Insert php include with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I haven't found a clear answer for this at all. I've been looking for an hour or two.

I have a PHP page doing SQL call and building out my page. I have a list of items with onClick JavaScript functions that trigger the page's additional events. Among other things, I need that onClick function to append the HTML page with additional PHP code. I've been hopping to append in a PHP file via an include but that seems unavailable to me using this JS function.

And ideas would be most helpful. If you can support your answer with code references or existing tutorials that make since that would be fantastic.

Comment: HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files, JS belongs in `.js` files. Just include a `<script>` reference somewhere in your HTML output, and you'll be fine.

Comment: PHP: Serverside, Javascript/HTML: Clientside. When your Javascript gets executed, your PHP code is already converted into output readable for the browser. You have to read about ajax in order to do such things.

Comment: PHP runs on the web server. Javascript runs in the browser. An include won't work for you, but you *can* do an ajax call to get the additional file and then insert it into the page from the browser.

Comment: PHP runs before the page is displayed, but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830857/how-to-append-a-div-via-php-and-ajax-post

Comment: I understand the basics of where and when JS and PHP run, hence my issues. it's "unavailable" as mentioned. I'm looking for a way to circumvention this issue. A different way to attach the problem to achieve a solution and allows the needed outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is code that executes in the client's browser, PHP is code that executes on the server. Attempting to output PHP from JavaScript will **never** work.

If you wish to trigger PHP code via JavaScript, you could make an [XML Http Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) to a PHP file on your server.

Comment: But, OP, if you're going to do ajax, don't do it yourself. Use a library like jQuery or MooTools.

Comment: @JonathanM Unless you are targeting IE6, there is no need for a JavaScript library. The `XMLHttpRequest` object is supported by all modern browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest#Browser_compatibility

Comment: yes, but there are 1001 exceptions to deal with when handling ajax by yourself. The libraries have already covered those exceptions. Robust ajax requires libraries, not just a function or two.

Comment: Best source. Please see sited answered question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971254/javascript-xmlhttprequest-open-php-file-and-execute-more-javascript

Comment: @DigitalKrony, save yourself some headaches. Take a good look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I took the link above, gave it a read and wrote this. Works just fine in Chrome, IE, and Safari. 

`xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    document.getElementById("liveProject").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","data/includes/project.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();`

Comment: @Greg - Any idea why the JavaScript on the page loaded doesn't work and/or a way to get things to kick start properly?

Comment: @DigitalKrony Use Google Chrome's web inspector or Firefox's Firebug to debug your JavaScript, it will show you where any errors are, and allow proper debugging, breaking, inspecting, etc.

Comment: @greg - The script is good, its how its being added into the page. JavaScript doesn't run simply from being added. I need to get more creative on how I access the information I need.

Comment: @DigitalKrony JavaScript *does* run from simply being added.

Comment: @greg - right, I have to get more creative oh how to pass my information around. I'm sure I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JQuery+Ajax to load an external file and then just append the element, for example:

```
// when the page loads
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
      $("#results").append(html);
    });
});
```

or

```
// when the an element is clicked
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.fn.appendElement = function (){
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
      $("#results").append(html);
    });
  }
});

$('#buttonId').click(function(){ $(this).appendElement(); });
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX, with jQuery you could do this:

```
$.get('test.php', function(data) {
  $("#MyDiv").html(data);
});
```

This would insert "test.php" generated content inside `<div id="MyDiv">`.

Ok. You don't want jQuery... The same above using plain javascript:

```
function getHTTPObject() {
  var xmlhttp;
  /*@cc_on
  @if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (E) {
        xmlhttp = false;
      }
    }
  @else
  xmlhttp = false;
  @end @*/
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  return xmlhttp;  
}

function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

function AJAX_GetAsinc(ajax, id, url) {
  ajax.abort();
  function statechange() {
    if ((ajax.readyState==4) && (ajax.status==200)) $(id).innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
  }
  ajax.open('GET', url, true);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = statechange;
  ajax.send(null);
}

var ajax = getHTTPObject();

AJAX_GetAsinc(ajax, 'MyDiv', 'test.php'); // This loads the content
```

Ohhh yes... this is less confusing :S

Comment: DigitalKrony does not mention jQuery in his question. As the question covers fundamental concepts, using a JavaScript library in an answer like this can cause confusion.

Comment: @DigitalKrony, Yes, we're talking about stuff you're not familiar with, but you'll have greater confusion if you try to build the ajax library yourself. Take a bit of time to read/study about what ajax is, then check out the jQuery library and its ajax function. It really is the right way to deal with what you're wanting to do.

Comment: @Greg trying to archieve what he asks without a framework like jQuery is far more confusing... try to explain how to build the XMLHttpRequest object and manage DOM with plain javascript. And make everything browser safe :S

Answer (score 1):

Using ajax is the solution. :)
What ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) does is run an external php page and returns its results dynamically without reloading the page. :)

Of course another solution would be to have your html file in .php and just echo the php you want added.